# Cannot change screen brightness after changing windows

Tags: windows-7, laptop, brightness

I have an "HP Pavilion Power Laptop 15-cb0xx" laptop, it has initially windows 10 installed on it.

For several reasons, I install windows 7 professional 64-bit on it instead of windows 10.

But now, I can not adjust the screen brightness neither from keyboard buttons nor from the control panel (the adjuster bar even does not exist).

What I must do?

Comment: Go to hp's official website, according to the machine model, download win7 system hotkey driver, power management software. Reinstall the driver of the video card.

Comment: i put my machine model in hp official website, but i only see windows 10 for it (my machine originally comes with windows 10), so what should i do ?